# How to calculate the flux of a galaxy merger?

Tags: observational-astronomy, galaxy, flux

Say three galaxies, with equal fluxes, $f_1$, merge. How could I calculate their combined flux?

Comment: How much do you know about each galaxy? 3D maps of stars and dust ready for some computational dynamics? I think this question has context and you haven't yet shared any. If it's related to a class or a problem set in a book, then can you add what topics been introduced so far? *Thanks!*

Comment: Merging may induce star bursts and AGN activity, but also quenching, so the combined luminosity could go both ways. The result depends to a large degree on the mass ratio of the systems, as well as their relative inclination angle. As @uhoh says, much more details are needed, but even with those it’s not possible to predict the outcome in general.